# I have included datatables cdn but it is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, cdn

I have created only one file index.php

1. in the header part I have included CSS link form the datatables.net

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="Description" content="Enter your description here"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


<title>Crud application</title>
</head>
```

2. I have given the id as table in body section

```html
<table class="table" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Sno</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Descriptioin</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

3. I have included JS CDN from datables.net and also the function at the end of the body tag

```html
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
</body>
```

4. but the tables are displaying as shown in the datatables.net.
   there are no errors in the console.
5. full code

```html
<?php
//INSERT INTO `note` (`sno`, `title`, `description`, `tstamp`) VALUES (NULL, 'Buy fruits', 'buy fruits now', current_timestamp());
    
     $insert = false;
     $server = "localhost";
     $user = "root";
     $password = "";
     $dbase = "notes";

     // create a connection
     $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $dbase);

     // die connection if not connected 
     if(!$conn){
       die("sorry connection not established".mysqli_connect_error());
     }
// updating the database 
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
         $title = $_POST['title'];
         $description = $_POST['description'];
     } 
     global $title; global $description;
// adding the query
     $sqld = "INSERT INTO `note` (`title`, `description`) VALUES ('$title', '$description')";
     $resultd = mysqli_query($conn, $sqld);
// checking the query wether updated
    if($resultd){
      //echo "success";
      $insert = true;
    }
    else{
      echo "not success". mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="Description" content="Enter your description here"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


<title>Crud application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PHP Crud</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <?php
       if($insert){
         echo"<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
         <strong>Success</strong> your notes submitted successfully.
         <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
           <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
         </button>
       </div>";
       }
      ?>
<div class="container my-4">
    <form action="/crud/index.php" method="POST">
        <h2>Add a note</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Note title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="note">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">note description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add note</button>
      </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <table class="table" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Sno</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Descriptioin</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `note`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "<tr>
      <th scope='row'>". $row['sno']."</th>
      <td>". $row['title']."</td>
      <td>". $row['description']."</td>
      <td>Actions</td>
       </tr>";
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

6) screenshot
[screentshot of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOEFy.png)

Comment: In order to be able to assist you, please post the complete code of all the steps your described above.

Comment: I have made a working example and it seems fine. There isn't any data going into the table yet, so Im not sure what you're expecting to see...

Comment: search table and number of entries is not displaying

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and looks clunky and out of place when used in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Make these changes: (1) Change `$('#myTable').DataTable();` to `$('#mytable').DataTable();` so that it matches the ID you are actually using in your table: `<table class="table" id="mytable">`. (2) Add `https:` to the two URLs which start with `//....`.

Comment: Also recommended: (1) Check your browser's console for error messages (hit F12 to open it). (2) Make sure your table has a closing `</table>` tag (it is missing in the question).

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

(1) Change $('#myTable').DataTable(); to $('#mytable').DataTable();
this worked fine for me and displayed my search table